# Swift: how to suppress interpretation of special characters and provide string literal

Tags: ios, json, swift, string

The goal is to serialize a Swift object by converting it to a JSON object then converting the JSON object into a JSON string that can be passed over the wire and decoded on the other side.

The problem is producing a valid JSON string.

Newlines must be escaped in a JSON string, but Swift interprets special characters in the escaped string instead of treating the string as a literal.

For example:

```
let a = "foobar\nhello\nworld"
let escapedString = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")

print(escapedString)
```

What gets printed is `foobar\nhello\nworld` instead of the desired `foobar\\nhello\\nworld`.

How do you tell Swift to treat a string as a literal and not to interpret special characters within?

**UPDATE**

As OOPer points out, using `debugPrint` shows the `\\n` characters remaining intact.

However, when paired with `evaluateJavaScript` in `WKWebView`, the `\\n` characters are turned into `\n`, which is the root issue. For example:

```
let script = "\(callback)(\'\(escapedString)\')"        
webView!.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (object: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    print("Done invoking \(callback)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no unescaped string syntax like in javascript template literals which is probably what you are looking for; maybe they will add it in the future.  Unfortunately you therefore have to escape each back slash which sometimes looks very scray, as in your example.

```
  //This is the same as `foobar\nhello\nworld` where each char is a literal
  let a = "foobar\\nhello\\nworld"  
  let escapedString = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\\\\n")
  //This outputs `foobar\\nhello\\nworld`
  print(escapedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just mistaking to interpret the output from `print`.

When you get `foobar\nhello\nworld` from `print(escapedString)`, `escapedString` contains 20 characters -- `f` `o` `o` `b` `a` `r` `\` `n` `h` `e` `l` `l` `o` `\` `n` `w` `o` `r` `l` `d`.

This is a valid JSON string when enclosed between `"`s.

If you want to check the escaped result in String-literal-like notation, you can use `debugPrint`:

```
let a = "foobar\nhello\nworld"
let escapedString = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")

print(escapedString) //->foobar\nhello\nworld
debugPrint(escapedString) //->"foobar\\nhello\\nworld"
```

---

For **UPDATE**

When using with `evaluateJavaScript`, you'd better think what is the right code as JavaScript, if you want to represent a JSON escaped string in JavaScript, you would write in .js file (or in `<script>...</script>`):

```
someFunc('foobar\\nhello\\nworld');
```

So, you may need to write something like this:

```
let a = "foobar\nhello\nworld"
let escapedForJSON = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")
//In actual code, you may need a little more...
let escapedForJavaScriptString = escapedForJSON.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "\\\\")

let script = "\(callback)(\'\(escapedForJavaScriptString)\')"
webView!.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (object: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    print("Done invoking \(callback)")
}
```

Comment: This is a great point, so maybe should post more code where the \\n goes away when used inside of `evaluateJavaScript.`

Comment: updated question, would love your feedback on the root issue